# Powershell: Add new line in multiple columns of CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, export-csv

I have data in an csv file looking like this:

| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 34 | Val M |
| 99 | 42 | Val Z |

So far this allows me to add lines above it

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath some.csv -NoNewLine -Value (
  @'
New line 1 above header
New line 2 above header

'@ + (Get-Content -Raw some.csv)
)
```

So with the above, row 1 and 2 both have in the first column
"New line 1 above header"
and
"New Line 1 above header"
And the rest of the data is left the way it originally was (which is what I want).
What I need to know is how to add a new line like i have been doing but I want to be able to add to the other columns next to it as well.

So lets say first row in the first cell has as you saw above.
But now in the second column of the first row, I want to add text saying "anything can go here".

Ideal output

| Title |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Company 1 Address | Company 2 Address |  |
| Company 1 Zip | Company 2 Zip |  |
| --------------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ |
| Heading 1 | Heading 2 | Heading N |
| --------------------- | ------------------ | ------------------ |
| 12 | 34 | Val M |
| 99 | 42 | Val Z |

Edit 1: I dont know why the extra dashes appear, but i dont want that

```
Set-Content -LiteralPath sample.csv -NoNewLine -Value (
  @'
Title
From/De:,To/A:
Name1,Name2
Add1,Add2
Zip1,Zip2
'@ + (Get-Content -Raw sample.csv)
)
```

If any of the names or addresses have a comma in them, putting them inside double quotes will escape them.

Comment: This is replacing the headers tho, not adding a new row in the position 0 (below the headers) are you sure that's what you intend to do? In any case, if you want to add data to the 2nd Column just add the delimiter which is most likely a comma.

Comment: Can you write out (like you did with the table) what you want your output to look like. Like @SantiagoSquarzon mentions, a Comma-Separated Values (CSV) file forms "columns" based on commas separating the data. Open the CSV file in Notepad, and you will see the format.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than try to manipulate the raw csv file, you can import the data from csv, modify it and then export it back to csv afterwards.

Something like this might work:

```
$csv = @"
Heading 1, Heading 2, Heading N
12, 34, Val M
99, 42, Val Z
"@;

# use Import-Csv to read from a csv file instead
$data = @( $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv );

# output the original data so we can see what it looks like
$data
#Heading 1 Heading 2 Heading N
#--------- --------- ---------
#12        34        Val M
#99        42        Val Z

# create the new rows
$newRows = @(
    (new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
        "Heading 1" = "first new row column 1"
        "Heading 2" = "first new row column 2"
        "Heading N" = "first new row column N"
    })),
    (new-object PSCustomObject -Property ([ordered] @{
        "Heading 1" = "second new row column 1"
        "Heading 2" = "second new row column 2"
        "Heading N" = "second new row column N"
    }))
);

# add the new rows to the start of the data
$data = $newRows + $data;

# output the updated data we can see what it looks like now
$data
#Heading 2               Heading 1               Heading N
#---------               ---------               ---------
#first new row column 2  first new row column 1  first new row column N
#second new row column 2 second new row column 1 second new row column N
#34                      12                      Val M
#42                      99                      Val Z

# export the new data back to the csv file
$data | Export-Csv -Path "some.csv" -NoTypeInformation;
```

Note - The problem with trying to manipulate raw csv text is if your data contains syntax characters like `"` or `,` or newline characters you probably won't escape them properly and it'll potentially corrupt your csv file.